# How to make an Enumerable Range List of Lists?

Tags: c#

I can make a List of `chars` like this:

```
List<char> letter = Enumerable.Range(0, 10)
                              .Select(i => '\0')
                              .ToList();
```

And a List of `int?` like this:

```
List<int?> number = Enumerable.Range(0, 10)
                              .Select(i => (int?)i)
                              .ToList();
```

And call them by `letter[1] = 'a'` and `number[1] = 5`.

---

How can I make a `List` (or `HashSet`) of 10 `List<char>`'s?

Something like:

```
List<char> myList = Enumerable.Range(0, 10)
                              .Select(i => List<char> i)
                              .ToList();
```

`myList[1]`, `myList[2]`, `myList[3]`

---

I want to loop through and add items to each list.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    myList[i].Add(letter[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine your two approaches as follows:

```
List<List<char>> myList = Enumerable.Range(0, 10)
     .Select(i => Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(c => '\0').ToList())
     .ToList();
```